# Add a right-click menu in el-tabs

Tags: element-ui

Add a right-click menu inside, close the right, close the left, and close the current and so on,
I tried to import the package with NPM, but it still didn't work

Comment: your question is not clear. Please improve the description of what you want to achieve, what have you done so far. If possible share the sample code so the reader can understand the question

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example